# redirect example.com/page to www.example.com/page

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with my htaccess redirects. when I type in example.com/page,it is redirected to example.com instead of example.com/page .How to fix this?
Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^page$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/page" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^page/?$ https://www.example.com/page [R=301,L]
```

***Fixes with OP's attempted code:***

- We need not to escape `.` on right side while url rewriting, that is needed when we are trying to match it as a regex in left side of RewriteRule/RewriteCond part.
- Then we need NOT use `"` to cover url part in right side(which you used in your last line of shown htaccess file), its not correct syntax.

***NOTE:*** Also in case your page(shown as per samples) is a non existing directory or file then we may need to write further rules to avoid 404 error or so.

Comment: is it okay if i use a guest account in testing urls?

Comment: @johnmichaelvillamor, sorry I didn't get it, could you please explain more on it, thank you.